# SQL Syntax Error in print functions using dynamic variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run the below query, It does print the statements but throws the following error:

> Process failed: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table_1')
    DELETE [dbo].[Table_1] 
    WHERE [UPDATED_DATE] <= DATEADD(dd, -90,'2018.02.23')

UPDATE DBO.T_REF_MASTER 
SET LAST_PURGE_DATE = GETDATE() 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_1'
```

Can someone explain why is it throwing that error because when I run the individual statements one by one, it executes perfectly

```
--Query
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLExist VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(10) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(200) = 'Table_1'
DECLARE @NO_OF_DAYS VARCHAR(10) = '90'
DECLARE @LAST_PURGE_DATE VARCHAR(50) = '2018-02-22 10:46:49.953'

SET @SQLExist = 'IF EXISTS((SELECT 1 FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' 
                        + @db + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + 
''')' 
               --PRINT @SQLExist 
               SET @SQL = 'DELETE [' + @db + '].[' + @TABLE_NAME
                         + '] where [UPDATED_DATE] <= DATEADD(dd, -'
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NO_OF_DAYS) + ',''' + 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@LAST_PURGE_DATE, 102) + ''')'
              --PRINT @SQL
              SET @S = 'UPDATE DBO.T_REF_MASTER SET LAST_PURGE_DATE = 
getdate() WHERE TABLE_NAME = '
                       + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TABLE_NAME) + ''');'
PRINT @SQLExist
print @SQL
PRINT @S
```

Comment: From [`VarChar(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify a length. Another best practice is to use [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when assembling object names in strings.

Answer (score 0):

I see two opening parentheses - (( - after EXISTS, but only one closing after @TABLE_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Okay agreed George. I removed those parentheses. Here's the new query:

```
--Query
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLExist VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(10) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(200) = 'Table_1'
DECLARE @NO_OF_DAYS VARCHAR(10) = '90'
DECLARE @LAST_PURGE_DATE VARCHAR(50) = '2018-02-22 10:46:49.953'

SET @SQLExist = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' 
                    + @db + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + 
''')' 
           --PRINT @SQLExist 
           SET @SQL = 'DELETE [' + @db + '].[' + @TABLE_NAME
                     + '] where [UPDATED_DATE] <= DATEADD(dd, -'
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NO_OF_DAYS) + ',''' + 
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@LAST_PURGE_DATE, 102) + ''')'
          --PRINT @SQL
          SET @S = 'UPDATE DBO.T_REF_MASTER SET LAST_PURGE_DATE = 
getdate() WHERE TABLE_NAME = '
                   + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TABLE_NAME) + ''''
PRINT @SQLExist
print @SQL
PRINT @S
```

Its still spitting out the SYNTAX ERROR NEAR ')'